# Setting multiple attributes select form Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, drop-down-menu

I have a drop-down menu that lists a collection of locks. I would like to set two params when an option is selected:

1. :name =>  l.name (which works with the code below)
2. :device_id => l.id

   `<%= f.select(:name,  Lock.all.collect  {|l| [  l.name ] } ,{:include_blank => true} ) %>`

I've tried passing the value in a hidden_field, but the field isn't aware of the lock that was selected. Any input is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Hi you can do this:**

```
  <%= select_tag(:name, options_from_collection_for_select(Lock.all, :id, :name, params[:name]) )%>
```

**or in your controller add this code:**

```
@locks = Lock.find(:all)
```

**and in your views**

```
 <%= select_tag(:name, options_from_collection_for_select(@locks, :id, :name, params[:name]) )%>
```

when you submit your form that contains this select_tag the params[:name] will get the selected name from the url of your app.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

So You need to get two values in controller side ?

Ex:-

I have below values in my db

```
ID Name
4  gggg
5  tttt
2  iiii
```

So dropdown will show the all names gggg,tttt,iiii if you select tttt from dropdown in server you required both 5, tttt ***right?***

Then you need to use below code

In controller

```
@locks = Lock.all.map{|l| [l.name, "#{l.id};#{l.name}"]}
```

In your view

```
<%= select_tag(:name, options_from_collection_for_select(@locks) )%>
```

So it will send the both id and name values saparated by ";" .

In your controller you need to split by ";"